# Change functionality of Laravel 4 Guard class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to write an SSO implementation and for that I need to override some methods such as `Auth::check()` which are implemented in the `Guard` class.

I don't understand, however, how to extend that class using service providers. I tried looking in the `AuthServiceProvider` but there is a whole lot of mumbo jumbo going on I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Fairly simple:

```
<?php

namespace Animekyun\Providers;

use Animekyun\Auth\CustomGuard;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SsoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        \Auth::extend('custom', function () {
            return new CustomGuard(
                new EloquentUserProvider(
                    $this->app['hash'],
                    $this->app['config']['auth.model']),
                $this->app['session.store']);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

and the `CustomGuard` class:

```
<?php
namespace Animekyun\Auth;


use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;

class CustomGuard extends Guard
{
    public function check() {
        // do some stuff
        return parent::check();
    }
}
```